# Prove that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product on $H.$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and $L$ be a Banach limit on $l_{\infty}.$
    Denote $S:H \rightarrow H$ as an invertible bounded linear map and there exists positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that 
    $$c\|x\| \leq \|S^nx \| \leq C \| x \|$$
    for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in H.$
    Define an map $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle : H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by 
    $$\langle x,y\rangle  = L(((S^nx,S^ny))_{n \in \mathbb{N}})$$
    Show that $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle $ is an inner product on $H.$

My attempt:

Note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in H,$ we have $(S^nx,S^nx) = \| S^n x \|^2 \geq 0.$ 
Therefore, by the property of Banach limit, it follows that 
$$\langle x,x\rangle  = L(((S^nx,S^nx))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = L((\| S^nx\|^2)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) \geq 0.$$

If $x = 0,$ then $(S^n(0), S^n(0)) = \|S^n(0)\|^2 = \| 0\| = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
Hence, by the property of Banach limit, 
$$\langle x,x\rangle  = (0,0) = L(((S^n(0),S^n(0)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = 0.$$

If $\langle x,x\rangle  = 0 = L(((S^nx,S^nx))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = L((\| S^nx \|^2)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}),$ then $\| S^nx\| = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
By assumption, we have $\| x \| = 0 $, which implies that $x = 0.$

For any $x,y \in H,$ we have 
$$(x,y) = L(((S^nx,S^ny))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = L(((S^ny,S^nx))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = (y,x).$$

I do not know how to show $\langle \alpha x + \beta x^{\prime} , y\rangle  = \alpha \langle x,y\rangle  + \beta \langle x^{\prime}, y\rangle $ and $\langle x, \alpha y + \beta y^{\prime}\rangle  = \alpha \langle x,y\rangle  + \beta \langle x,y^{\prime}\rangle .$

UPDATE (Bilinearity):

For any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,x^{\prime},y\in H$, we have 
    $$(S^n(\alpha x + \beta x^{\prime}), S^n(y)) = (\alpha S^n(x) + \beta S^n(x^{\prime}), S^n(y)) = \alpha (S^n(x), S^n(y)) + \beta (S^n(x^{\prime}), S^n(y)).$$
    It follows that 
    \begin{align*}
 \langle \alpha x + \beta x^{\prime},y \rangle & = L(((S^n(\alpha x + \beta x^{\prime}),S^n(y)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) \\ 
 & = L((\alpha (S^n(x), S^n(y)) + \beta (S^n(x^{\prime}), S^n(y)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) \\
 & = \alpha L(((S^n(x),S^n(y)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) + \beta L(((S^n(x^{\prime}),S^n(y)))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) \\
 & = \alpha \langle x , y \rangle + \beta \langle x^{\prime},y \rangle.
 \end{align*}
    Similarly, we have $\langle x , \alpha y + \beta y^{\prime} \rangle= \alpha \langle x,y \rangle + \beta \langle x, y^{\prime} \rangle$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y,y^{\prime} \in H.$
    Therefore, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on $H.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: For each $n$, the map $S^n$ is linear. Hence the map $(x,y) \mapsto \bigl((S^nx, S^ny)_H\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bilinear.

Comment: Do do you mean $\langle x, y \rangle = \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (S^n x, S^n y)$ as a limit in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Can I please ask where the question is from? It might be related to a problem which I am thinking about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't use `<` and `>` for inner products. Those produce *relation* symbols, which both look different and give wrong spacing, besides. Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead. They show as $\langle$ and $\rangle$ and get spaced like delimiters should.

Comment: A Banach limit is a linear functional. Doesn't this make the bilinearity of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ trivial? Or did I miss something?

Comment: One more thing: Your argument that $\langle x,x\rangle=0$ implies $x=0$ is not so good. But if $x\ne0$, you get $(S^nx,S^nx)=\|S^nx\|^2\ge c^2\|x\|^2$ for all $n$, and that impiies $\langle S^nx,S^nx\rangle\ge c^2\|x\|^2$

Comment: @Fan: This question is taken from 'An Introductory Course in Functional Analysis' by Adam Bowers and Nigel Kalton, Chapter $3$ exercises.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Oops, I forgot that Banach limit is a linear functional. That settles my problem.